# Progress ABL to C# - How to convert "EMPTY temp-table" statement in C#?

Tags: progress-4gl, epicorerp

I'm currently converting a BPM from Epicor 9 to Epicor 10 (Progress ABL to C#). I came across this statement "EMPTY temp-table" in the progress code. I was wondering what is the equivalent of this in C#?

```
EMPTY temp-table ttRcvHead NO-ERROR.
```

Does simply assigning a 'null' to the variable does the job?

```
ttRcvHead = null;
```

Or creating a new object of the type is the right thing to do here?

```
ttRcvHead = new Erp.Tablesets.RcvHeadRow();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your datatable:

myDataTable.Rows.Clear();

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is followed by the statement : DELETE object hReceipt. So here hReceipt=null?

Comment: hReceipt is most likely a just handle to the table or query. These are things that are done within the transaction or context in .NET.